# How do I add a space in a label with vbscript?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, vbscript

I am labeling point features in Acrmap 10.3.  I have the points labeled with three fields from the attributes on the same line, but there is no space between them.  what is the expression to add a space?

Comment: See if adding & " " & between each field works for you.  That is a single space between the parentheses.

Comment: This did not work.  It said the 'expression contains an error.'  This is what I currently have for my expression:   [points] &vbsameline& [POINT_X] &vbsameline& [POINT_Y]

Comment: ok, I figured it out.  all I did was change it to python, and it automatically changed my expression to python and it now has spaces.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this would work:

```
[Field_1]&" "&[Field_2]&" "&[Field_3]
```

or this (as long as all of your fields are strings):

```
[Field_1]+" "+[Field_2]+" "+[Field_3]
```

Comment: That works but the python parser is preferred, rumor is that support for VBScript is being depreciated - that's the intention from Esri. In python I would use "{} {} {}".format([Field_1],[Field_2],[Field_3]) - the string.format function will display strings, integers, floats - almost anything in the same way.. it only gets fussy if you want to restrict decimal places or pad with zeros. You can also add new lines by using the formatting string "{}\n{}\n{}".format([Field_1],[Field_2],[Field_3]).

Comment: I just changed it from VB to Python and it automatically changed my expression to python and now it has spaces between the fields.